# Static HTML to dynamic WordPress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to convert my HTML to WordPress, everything works fine and perfect. But for some reason my font awesome icons are not showing and they are showing as a square.
How can I fix this, thank you.[html link to fontawesome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uL0To.png) [Square icons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5eXnz.png)

‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎

Comment: There is a [dedicated site](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) for WordPress questions. Next time, post your question there.

Comment: Your path is incorrect, if you are using a third-party url then don't use the template directory, just use the third-party URL

`<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/66adbc22e6.js crossorigin="anonymous">`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using someone else’s theme the easiest way is to use the [WPCode plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/insert-headers-and-footers/) to insert additional lines in the head section of your HTML.

But if you’ve created your own theme, as you may have done if you’re converting an HTML site to WordPress, then you can simply add this code to `functions.php`, inserting your kit code where I put `xxxxx`:

```
function my_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'font-awesome', 'https://kit.fontawesome.com/xxxxx.js' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue_scripts' );
```